# View model not returning any data after reloading fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Trying to implement:

1.An internet check before loading data from view model.
2.The fragment shouldn't fetch any data(doesn't set any observer) from view model and shows alert dialog if their is no connection.
3.If connection is available reload/fetch data from view model using "try again" button inside alert dialog.

Problem:
But when trying to reload the data from try again button,no data is getting fetched from view model. It doesn't happen if I have internet connection available from beginning,then view model works just fine. But if I don't have internet from beginning and try to reload the data again from "try again" button then happens.

I have also tried to reload the whole fragment instead of just calling the "getDataFromViewModel" method using below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).commitNow();
            getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(this).commitNow();
        } else {
            getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        }
```

but this also doesn't work.

Here is my fragment class:

```
public class GlobalDataFragment extends Fragment implements AlertDialogClass.AlertDialogClickInterface {


    public GlobalDataFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication())).get(GlobalDataViewModel.class);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_global_data, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        totalCase = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalCases);
        activeCase = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvActiveCases);
        recovered = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRecovered);
        caseToday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTodayCase);
        casePM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCasesPM);
        todayDeath = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTodayDeaths);
        totalDeath = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalDeaths);
        deathsPM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDeathsPM);
        criticalCondition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCriticalCase);
        totalTested = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTested);
        testsPM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTestsPM);
        affectedCountries = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAffectedCountries);
        simpleArcLoader = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleArcLoader);
        pieChart = (PieChart) view.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
        nestedScrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        alertDialogClass = new AlertDialogClass(getContext(), this);


        getDataFromViewModel();


    }

    private void getDataFromViewModel() {
        try {
            if (CheckConnection.isConnected()) {

                viewModel.getGlobalData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), this::setViewData);

            } else {

                alertDialogClass.show();

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void setViewData(GlobalData globalData) {

        if (globalData != null) {
            totalTested.setText(globalData.getTests());
            testsPM.setText(globalData.getTestsPerOneMillion());
            affectedCountries.setText(globalData.getAffectedCountries());


            setPieGraph(globalData);
            simpleArcLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    }

//Called when clicked on try again button of alert dialog
    @Override
    public void OnAlertButtonClicked() {

        alertDialogClass.dismiss();
        getDataFromViewModel();

    }
}
```

My view model Class:

```
public class GlobalDataViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private Repository repository;
    private LiveData<GlobalData> globalData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public GlobalDataViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        repository = Repository.getInstance();
        globalData = repository.getGlobalData();

    }


    public void init() {

    }

    public LiveData<GlobalData> getGlobalData() {
        return globalData;
    }
}
```

My fragment looks like this when an internet connection occurs:
[image: Alert Dialog]

After pressing try again the method(getDataFromViewModel) is called but view model is not returning any data.But the same method is working fine when I load the fragment having internet from the beginning.Is it happening because of the way i initialize and set observer on view model or something else?Please help and suggest me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt show your repository config, anyhow I believe your problem is that you are fetching data from your repository (in this case what I believe to be in an external network [internet]) without internet and you are not trying to fetch again, to sum up, you are observing this:

```
private LiveData<GlobalData> globalData = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

And as you didn't have internet connection at the time you initialize your viewmodel it is empty.

What you can do to fix it:

```
private LiveData<GlobalData> globalData = repository.getGlobalData();
```

This way, you are only going to trigger a network fetch if/when you observe this *globalData*

let me know if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you brother.You are right on point with the reason which was causing this problem.As you said I removed this part `globalData = repository.getGlobalData();` to another method : `public void init() {
        if (globalData==null)
            globalData = repository.getGlobalData();
    }`. Calling that method only when their is a working internet connection made sure that I wasn't trying to trigger a network fetch without having internet as you pointed out.Now it works just fine.Thanks again